# Problems performing a query, using MAX inside a WHERE in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query about dates, the problem comes to me when I try to use the maximum date of a field, because I think I should use a having when using the MAX operator, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
SELECT SubscriberKey AS IdContact,
    SUM(ord.SalePrice) / COUNT(line.IdOrderLocator) AS SpentOlderSeason,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ord.IdOrderLocator) / COUNT(line.IdOrderLocator) AS OrdersOlderSeason,
    SUM(line.Units) AS TotalItemsOlderSeason,
    MAX(DATEDIFF(Day, zone.StartDate, DATEADD(year, -1, getDate()))) / COUNT(DISTINCT ord.IdOrderLocator) AS PurchaseFrequencyOlderSeason
FROM AR_NS_ORDERS AS ord
INNER JOIN AR_NS_ORDERS_LINE AS line
  ON ord.IdOrderLocator = line.IdOrderLocator
INNER JOIN AR_NS_ZONES AS zone
  ON line.Destination = zone.IdZone
WHERE ord.Status != 'ANNULLED'
  AND zone.Season = IIF(MAX(zone.EndDate) >= getDate(), YEAR(zone.EndDate)-1, YEAR(zone.EndDate))
  AND ord.CreatedDate BETWEEN zone.StartDate AND DATEADD(year, -1, getDate())
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
```

The error he throws is:

> Error saving the Query field.An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE
>   clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a
>   select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Thank you very much

Comment: You will need to use a subquery here.

Comment: @Raul . . . `IIF()` doesn't exist in MySQL.  Are you sure you have tagged the database correcctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using SQL Server.  If I understand correctly you can use a subquery to calculate the maximum and use that in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey AS IdContact,
       SUM(ord.SalePrice) / COUNT(line.IdOrderLocator) AS SpentOlderSeason,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ord.IdOrderLocator) / COUNT(line.IdOrderLocator) AS OrdersOlderSeason,
       SUM(line.Units) AS TotalItemsOlderSeason,
       MAX(DATEDIFF(Day, zone.StartDate, DATEADD(year, -1, getDate()))) / COUNT(DISTINCT ord.IdOrderLocator) AS PurchaseFrequencyOlderSeason
FROM AR_NS_ORDERS ord JOIN
     AR_NS_ORDERS_LINE line
     ON ord.IdOrderLocator = line.IdOrderLocator JOIN
     (SELECT z.*, MAX(EndDate) OVER () as max_enddate
      FROM AR_NS_ZONES z
     ) zone
     ON line.Destination = zone.IdZone
WHERE ord.Status <> 'ANNULLED' AND
      zone.Season = (CASE WHEN max_EndDate >= getDate() THEN YEAR(zone.EndDate)-1 ELSE YEAR(zone.EndDate) END) AND
      ord.CreatedDate BETWEEN zone.StartDate AND DATEADD(year, -1, getDate())
GROUP BY SubscriberKey;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but the option you recommend gives me an error:   Error saving the Query field.An unmatched parenthesis occurs in the query.

Comment: @Raúl . . . There are no obvious unbalanced parentheses in the `FROM` or `WHERE` clauses where I made changes.

Comment: I finally found where a parenthesis was lost, thank you very much for your help !!!